# google buildpack psycopg2-binary Error: pg_config executable not found

Tags: python-3.x, docker, psycopg2, buildpack

This is in my requirements.txt
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3    # via -r requirements/base.in

that I am building inside docker image. I was under impression that if I install `psycopg2-binary vs psycopg2` I should not install additional postgresql devel libs. **Am I wrong?**

```sh
pack build --builder=gcr.io/buildpacks/builder:v1 test-python

Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
  Downloading psycopg2-binary-2.8.3.tar.gz (378 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /layers/google.python.runtime/python/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z7z_l56l/psycopg2-binary_ddfc5ed05bb44cf4b7e2f14d634bd6ae/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z7z_l56l/psycopg2-binary_ddfc5ed05bb44cf4b7e2f14d634bd6ae/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-vsc_2hlv
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-z7z_l56l/psycopg2-binary_ddfc5ed05bb44cf4b7e2f14d634bd6ae/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-vsc_2hlv/psycopg2_binary.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-vsc_2hlv/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-vsc_2hlv/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-vsc_2hlv/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-vsc_2hlv/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    
    Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are not wrong; I had the same issue today, and after a bit of googling I found this (solved) github issue: https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/699#

The comments there (https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/699#issuecomment-377188700) indicate one possible cause for the issue is using an outdated version of pip.

I was using version 18.x, and after upgrading it (`python -m pip install -U pip`, which got me pip 21.1.3), the installation of psycopg2-binary finished successfully (as expected) even though I don't have any postgres dev libraries installed.